# Ubuntu resolution when maximizing window

Tags: 16.04

[problem presented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOmcj.jpg)

My ubuntu suddenly freaked out and when I maximize the window the resolution doesn't fit my screens resolution, I have tried everything include searching here, I tried to change the resolution settings in my vm (VMWare 16 workstation) and inside the linux OS, but nothing worked. can someone please save me?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Try changing scale option to 1
go to setting -> display -> scale for menu and ti